# Run ps1 with admin privileges and unrestricted policies from a batch file?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have a test.bat to run a test.ps1 with admin privileges and unrestricted policies, and both are in the same folder (local PC), but the bat does't run ps1. Whats wrong?

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList 'Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force -File" "% ~ dpn0.ps1" "' -Verb RunAs}"
```

And my script is similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1097598/delete-file-process-with-powershell-using-environment-variables)

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems:

1. You have nested double-quotes that are confusing it, you need to [escape inner quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893309/escape-double-quotes-inside-batchs-input-parameters), and/or use single quotes inside the double quotes.
2. You have extra spaces in your call to "[%~DPN0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work)".
3. You are incorrectly concatenating the script name variable (%~DPN0) into your ArgumentList.
4. Start-Processes `ArgumentList` takes an array of strings (`string[]`), not a space-separated list.  To pass a static array of strings, separate the string items with commas.
5. You are also trying to run a `-command` *and* a `-file`, and you can't use both a `-file` argument and a `-command` argument in a single PowerShell.exe call.
6. You are trying to run a PowerShell command (`Set-ExecutionPolicy`) without specifying the `-command` argument.  To set the execution policy for the Powershell.exe session you are trying to run, use PowerShell.exe's `-ExecutionPolicy` parameter instead of trying to run the `Set-ExecutionPolicy` command.

Here's is the corrected version of your command:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted','-File %~dpn0.ps1' -Verb RunAs"
```

Comment: Works fine here,  and we're not a script writing service, so you'll have to do a little more, and provide more information.  Please edit your question and add exactly what you've attempted, and exactly what the results were of those tries, including the exact output from the batch file when you attempt to run it.

Comment: Also, for testing, make a test.ps1 that simply contains a basic PowerShell script (like `write-host "Hi!"` followed by `read-host` so it waits for you to hit enter), this will help determine if it's launching incorrectly, or if it's a problem with the PS1 script you're trying to run.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The problem is ps1. I fix it, but a have another problem, an re-edit my question to helpme with the second part, to select your answer with correct. Thanks a lot

Comment: If you have an different/additional problem, please start a new question instead of changing this one into something else...

Comment: no. all works fine. sorry